# Cannot install packages in Miktex

Tags: packages

Every time I try to install some packages using MikTex console, it just fails showing the following message:
[image]

Also, when I click Updates button, it also fails with the following message:
[image]

It seems that the problems happens from the common causation, which I don't know how to fix. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you using a proxy and if so, did you check that it is configured for MiKTeX? Is this a fresh MiKTeX installation?

Comment: Thank you for your hospitality :). I guessed the proxy might be the problem, so i deactivated it with explore. But it never worked. And it is a fresh MikTeX installation.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I would try the following: Doublecheck that the proxy is deactivated, reinstall MiKTeX and see if the MiKTeX console works now. If it still doesn't, contact the MiKTeX support (following the instructions [here](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)).

Comment: A reinstallation of MiKTeX also didn't work. I'll contact  the MiKTeX support. Thanks a lot for your advice!